# joomla get and set configurations for a component

Tags: php, joomla, configuration, joomla-extensions

For sometime I have been trying to create a simple admin form to use to save configurations and a way to access these configs from the site side without necessarily going to the database. I just can't seem to understand how this [documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_%28MVC%29_Component_for_Joomla!2.5_-_Part_13) can help me achieve this. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770837/joomla-2-5-get-component-configuration-in-config-xml-always-return-null?answertab=votes#tab-top) sheds some light on how to get the saved configurations but I am stuck on how and where to save the configs.

I am using joomla 2.5

It is a component i am trying to develop. On the site side of the application I have a method to get the configuration as:

```
//We add config code.
$componentParams = &JComponentHelper::getParams('com_rocket');
$param = $componentParams->get('speed', 'null');
```

This I believe will work fine however I have no idea how to save the configuration somewhere and have a way to edit it as well.

Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Create a simple admin form? Explain in more detail. What Joomla version are you using? Can you share your code? I assume this is for a component you have created right?

Comment: @Lodder I just updated the question to provide some more detail. Thanks for your time man.

Answer (score 1):

To get component parameters for Joomla 2.5, try using the following:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$componentParams = $app->getParams('com_rocket');
$param = $componentParams->get('speed', null);

// Display the result
echo $param;
```

And to set the component parameter, try this:

```
$value = "some value here";
$param->set('speed', $value);

$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->update($db->quoteName('#__extensions') . ' AS a')
      ->set('a.params = ' . $db->quote((string)$param))
      ->where('a.element = "com_rocket"');

$db->setQuery($query);
$db->query();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness sake. I finally managed to get how I could do it in a simpler manner.
To manage the configurations for a component all I needed to do was:

1. Create a config class in the admin folder

   ```
   <field
       name="speed"
       type="text"
       label="COM_ROCKET_CONFIG_FIELD_SPEED_LABEL"
       description="COM_ROCKET_CONFIG_FIELD_SPEED_DESC"
       default="200"
   /> 


       </fieldset>
   ```

1. In the view class I added the code below

   ```
   protected function addToolBar() { JToolBarHelper::title('settings'); JToolBarHelper::preferences('com_rocket'); }
   ```
2. in the display method I added a call to the above toolbar method

   ```
               // Set the toolbar
           $this->addToolBar();
   ```

and whallaa everything was taken care of.